# QuestDB Postgres wire protocol prevent connections from closing

Tags: questdb, psycopg3

I'm developing a telegram bot in Python using QuestDB as the database. I'm using psycopg3 library connecting to QuestDb over the postgres wire protocol in autocommit mode. The bot only executes SQL queries when it receives commands, but if the commands are more than 5 minutes apart I get the following error:

```
psycopg.OperationalError: consuming input failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

In QuestDB documentation I see a config parameter which looks relevant to my problem:

```
pg.net.connection.timeout=300000
```

But I'm not sure if setting this parameter to 0 is the correct way to solve this issue. So, my question is: how to properly configure QuestDb server so it doesn't close idle connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg.net.connection.timeout` is the correct setting to tweak in your case. `0` value is supported and treated as "no idle timeout" value.